# Map function returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, base64, blob

I was trying to convert a blob to base64, and I found my way around, but while waiting the result from the function `displayBase64String` the map function in `submitOffre` returns an empty string even though console.log prints some data.

I'll appreciate any solution
here is my code.

```
submitOffre = (saleData) => {
        debugger ;
        var result = base64Service.displayBase64String(saleData);
        console.log("========", result);
        const rs = result.map(value => value.file); // Doesn't work.
        console.log(rs); // rs is empty
    }
class Base64Service {

    blobToBase64 = (blob, callback) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var data = '';
        reader.onload = function () {
            var dataUrl = reader.result;
            var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
            callback(base64);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }

    displayBase64String(formProps) {
        const result = [];
        const outbut = Object.entries(formProps.imageToUpload).map(([key, value]) => {
            this.blobToBase64(value, (data) => {
                result.push({ "file": `data:${value.type};base64,${data}` })
            })
        });
        return result;
    };
} 
export default new Base64Service();
```

Comment: The `readAsDataURL` method is asynchronous, meaning the rest of the code won't wait for it to finish before it runs. So your `result.map` line is running before the reading is done, which is why there's not yet any data. (Likewise, your `displayBase64String` method is returning the result before the reading is done, too, so it'll return an empty array even right there.) You need to wait until the callback is run before you try to work with the data. (Or promisify the reading, but that's a slightly more advanced topic.)

Comment: I'm still kinda lost here, can you please tell how to do so with some code?

Comment: In your callback, you have only `result.push(...)`. THAT is where you need to also do your mapping and logging, otherwise you'll be working with data that hasn't yet finished reading.

Comment: I can't do the mapping there, because I need to send these data to the server.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code you've provided that you're sending anything to a server. But why can't you send it to the server in that callback?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might help:

I've modified your code a bit, just to show you the basic pattern.

If you're doing more than 1 image at a time, you will need to use `Promise.all`, to keep track of more than 1 promise at once.

```
submitOffre = async (saleData) => { // SEE THE async KEYWORD
        debugger ;
        var result = await blobToBase64(saleData); // SEE THE await KEYWORD
        console.log("========", result);
        const rs = result.map(value => value.file); // Doesn't work.
        console.log(rs); // rs is empty
    }
```

I'll treat as if you were converting only 1 image.

```
    blobToBase64 = (blob, callback) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var data = '';
        reader.onload = function () {
            var dataUrl = reader.result;
            var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
            callback(base64);
            resolve(base64);  // NOTE THE resolve() FUNCTION TO RETURN SOME VALUE TO THE await
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
```